# Consider monic orthogonal polynomials $\{\phi_{0},\phi_{1},\dots,\phi_{n}\}$. Show $||\phi_{k}||\leq||q||$ for all $q \in \Pi_{k}$ with degree $k$

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, inner-products, orthogonality

Consider monic orthogonal polynomials ${ \{\phi_{0}, \phi_{1},\dots, \phi_{n},\dots \}}$. We want to show that $||\phi_{k}||\leq||q||$ for all monic polynomials $q \in \Pi_{k}$ which are of exact degree $k$.

The norm here refers to the norm arising from the inner product: $ \langle f,g \rangle =\int_{a}^{b} w(x)f(x)g(x) \,\mathrm dx $ where $w$ is a positive weight function.

I was wondering how to approach this problem. I tried applying the definition of the norm and the recurrence relation on orthogonal polynomials, but I can't seem to get anywhere.

Comment: What is $k$ and how does it relate to $n$?

Comment: @TheoBendit Oops, sorry, $n$ is actually $k$, I'll edit it right now, thanks!

Comment: At a guess, would $\phi_n$ be of degree $n$?

Comment: @TheoBendit Yes, $n$ is the degree of $\phi_{n}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $$q=\phi_k+\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}a_j\phi_j.$$ By the Pythagoras theorem $$\|q\|^2=\|\phi_k\|^2+\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}|a_j|^2\|\phi_j\|^2\ge \|\phi_k\|^2.$$